# How to union two date vectors in R?

Tags: r, date, set

I have two (considerably long) date vectors, e.g.

```
> c1 <- c( as.Date( "2013-08-29" ), as.Date( "2013-08-30" ) )
> c2 <- c( as.Date( "2013-08-30" ), as.Date( "2013-08-31" ) )
```

and I am looking for some operation like

```
> union( c1, c2 )
[1] "2013-08-29" "2013-08-30" "2013-08-31"
```

The standard union operation in R returns

```
[1] 15946 15947 15948
```

Does anybody know a (short/elegant) solution to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `as.Date`

```
> as.Date(union(c1, c2))
[1] "2013-08-29" "2013-08-30" "2013-08-31"
```

Try this:

```
> as.Date(c(15946, 15947, 15948), origin = "1970-01-01")
[1] "2013-08-29" "2013-08-30" "2013-08-31"
```

Comment: I've tried that already, it throws: "Error in as.Date.numeric(union(c1, c2)) : 'origin' must be supplied."

Comment: I didnt get any error message, but if `origin` is requiered, then supply the date for the origin, see my edit.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative to use of `union`

```
 unique(c(c1,c2))
 [1] "2013-08-29" "2013-08-30" "2013-08-31"
```

Answer (score 1):

or use class(c3) = "Date"

```
> c1 = c( as.Date( "2013-08-29" ), as.Date( "2013-08-30" ) )
> c2 = c( as.Date( "2013-08-30" ), as.Date( "2013-08-31" ) )
> c3 = union(c1,c2)
> class(c3) = "Date"
> c3
[1] "2013-08-29" "2013-08-30" "2013-08-31"
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works, although I prefer the conversion with as.Date(...).